# iOS developer menu (Testing app under harsh condidions)

Tags: ios

Is there a developer settings menu under iOS, much like Androids developer settings menu? What I'm looking for is for tools to test my app under "harsh" conditions... In Android, the settings are "Destroy activities as soon as the user leaves them" and set no background processes (Or their iOS similarities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "harsh conditions" I generally come up against are bad network activities. I test that using the signal conditioner: http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/